# How to disable onboard (on-screen keyboard) that automatically starts when I log onto my system?

Tags: keyboard

whenever I login to my system (Ubuntu 13.10) `onboard` (on-screen keyboard) automatically runs. I don't want it to run any more. Why does it run automatically & how to disable it?

Long back as far as I remember, once I manually started `onboard`. And after that it starts on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your on screen keyboard is appearing at your login screen, find the circle with the little guy in it and click on him. You should be able to disable the keyboard  from there.

If that doesn't work, go to System Settings > Universal access and disable it from there.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in Gnome 3 (I have version 3.18), on-screen keyboard always appear.

Ugly but working workaround is to comment out the Exec line here:

`/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.Caribou.Daemon.service`

Comment: Definitely not a bug in gnome 3 as I'm using it (archlinux) and I've never had this issue.