# How to disable the on-screen keyboard when I use the touch screen?

Tags: fedora, gnome, touch-screen, accessibility

I am using Fedora on a computer with touch screen. When was using Fedora 26 or older, the on-screen keyboard always pops up when I am using the touch screen (like when I selected gedit window, the on-screen keyboard shows, and I have to close it manually). I found that caribou is the keyboard which annoys me, and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108368/#comment-422829) helped me (by disabling caribou).

However, after upgrading to Fedora 27 (actually I installed it from scratch), disabling caribou no longer works, and the keyboard pops up whenever I am using touch screen on gedit (and other applications). What should I do to disable it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use a GNOME shell extension called "[Block Caribou](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/)".

It claims to block caribou (the on screen keyboard) from popping up when you use a touchscreen in GNOME shell v3.26.

**Edit:** for later versions and if Block Caribou doesn't seem to help try the newer shell extension [Block Caribou 36](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3222/block-caribou-36/).

Comment: "Block Caribou" works well. Hope that it will continue supporting when gnome-shell updates (my gnome-shell version is 3.26.2-1.fc27)

Comment: For newer versions of gnome, try the newer extension "Block Caribou 36" https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3222/block-caribou-36/ - this worked for me on Fedora 33

Comment: @Lorna Please feel free to [edit] the answer and append this.

Comment: There are workaround instructions posted for Gnome 42 as a comment on https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/.

Answer (score -1):

if you click Activities< show applications< software. its way down at the bottom, and you can click uninstall. (its making me type 30 characters to post answer.